# 'str' object is not callable for string as array

Tags: python, string

I got an error saying "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" ;
This is my code:

```
m=input()  
while(m!='0'):  
    c=0  
    for letter in range(len(m)):  
        if(m(letter) == '1'or '2'):  
            c++  
        if((m(letter) == '7'or'8'or'9') and (m(letter -1)=='2')):  
            c--  
        if(m(letter)=='0'):  
            c--  
    print(c)  
    m=input()
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying that you are trying to call a string, and it's not callable. Looks like you want to get a char from a specified position in a string. Then, use `m[letter]` instead of `m(letter)`.

Also, your if conditions are not correct, e.g. instead of `if(m(letter) == '1'or '2'):` you should use `in`, like this: `if m[letter] in ('1', '2')`.

Also, there is no `++` and `--` in python, use `+=1` and `-=1` instead.

Also, there are some redundant parenthesis in `while` and `if` conditions.

Here's the improved code:

```
m = str(input())
while m != '0':
    c = 0
    for letter in range(len(m)):
        if m[letter] in ('1', '2'):
            c += 1
        if m[letter] in ('7', '8', '9') and m[letter - 1] == '2':
            c -= 1
        if m[letter] == '0':
            c -= 1
    print(c)
    m = str(input())
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: NB: You don't need to do `str(input())` in Python 3.x, `raw_input()` is renamed `input()`. Actually, you should probably use `raw_input()` in Python 2.x anyway, rather than `str(input())`.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few issues:

1. Python use square brackets for indexing: `m[letter]`.
2. Python doesn't have a post-increment operator. You have to use `c += 1`.
3. `a == 'b' or 'c' or 'd'` is interpreted as `(a == 'b') or ('c') or ('d')`, which will always be `True`. You want to do `a in ('b', 'c', 'd')`.

Comment: For the lazy: `a in 'bcd'`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: That'd also be true for `a = 'bc'`, which may not be something you want.

Comment: I had thought about including that caveat. This only makes sense when you are sure `a` is a single character. In this context it always will be, but I could see someone getting bitten by that.

Answer (score 1):

Either a string or a list, the indexing should be done using square bracket. So use

```
m[letter]
```

instead of `m(letter). By using paranthesis, you are calling a function`m`, which throws error since m is not a function and only a string